# How do I add a route which maps to a slug url generated by the stringex gem in ruby on rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

It seems simple, in my model I have:

```
class CustomerAccount < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_url :name

  def to_param
    url # or whatever you set :url_attribute to
  end

end
```

And in my controller, I have:

```
class CustomerAccountsController < ApplicationController
  def show # dashboard for account, set as current account
    @account = CustomerAccount.find_by_url params[:id]
    no_permission_redirect if !@account.has_valid_user?(current_user)
    set_current_account(@account)

    @latest_contacts = Contact.latest_contacts(current_account)
  end
end
```

What's currently in the routes.rb is:

```
  resources :customer_accounts, :path => :customer_accounts.url do
    member do
      get 'disabled'
      post 'update_billing'
    end
  end
```

That gives me the following error when I try to generate data via rake db:seed, or at least I assume the entry in routes is what's doing it.

```
undefined method `url' for :customer_accounts:Symbol
```

So what do I need to do to get the route set up?  What I'd like is http://0.0.0.0/customeraccountname to map to the view for the customer account page.

UPDATE:

Here is the code that ended up working in routes.rb, which I discovered after looking at the examples in the answer below:

```
  resources :customer_accounts, :path => '/:id' do
    root :action => "show"
    member do
      get 'disabled'
      post 'update_billing'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set it up so you have a route like you show, do this:

```
get '/:id', :to => "customer_accounts#show"
```

If you want the `disabled` and `update_billing` actions underneath this:

```
get '/:id/disabled', :to => "customer_accounts#disabled"
post '/:id/update_billing', :to => "customer_accounts#update_billing"
```

Alternatively (and *much* neater):

```
scope '/:id' do
  controller "customer_accounts" do
    root :action => "show"
    get 'disabled'
    get 'update_billing'
  end
end
```

Comment: What ended up working the way I wanted it to is in the update, which I hacked out after seeing your examples.